# How can I make the structure involve in main?

Tags: c

here is the program fragment:

```
struct part {
    int number;
    char name[NAME_LEN + 1];
    int on_hand;
}inventory[MAX_PARTS];
```

and my problem here is I want to include the structure in the main but I don't know how to do it. Let me put the main in here but there are also other functions that I couldn't show.

```
int main(void)
{
    char code;

    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter operation code: ");
        scanf(" %c", &code);
        while (getchar() != '\n')   /* skips to end of line */
            ;
        switch (code) {
        case 'i': insert();
            break;
        case 's': search();
            break;
        case 'u': update();
            break;
        case 'p': print();
            break;
        case 'q': return 0;
        default:  printf("Illegal code\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "involve in main"? What obstacles are preventing you from doing that?

Comment: I am studying a programming book and this a two step question.I wrote the first part with structure but now my goal is writing the structure in main function.

Comment: Simply declare variable(s) with the structure type and write some statements to write to the variable(s).

Answer (score 1):

YOu can simply do this, just put it all in one file

```
#define NAME_LEN 42
#define MAX_PARTS 99

struct part {
   int number;
   char name[NAME_LEN + 1];
   int on_hand;
}  inventory[MAX_PARTS];

   int main(void)
    {
    char code;

    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter operation code: ");
        scanf(" %c", &code);
        while (getchar() != '\n')   
            ;
        switch (code) {
        case 'i': insert();
            break;
        case 's': search();
            break;
        case 'u': update();
            break;
        case 'p': print();
            break;
        case 'q': return 0;
        default:  printf("Illegal code\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

or you can put in a separate header file , say 'part.h'

```
#define NAME_LEN 42
#define MAX_PARTS 99

struct part {
   int number;
   char name[NAME_LEN + 1];
   int on_hand;
};
```

Note the removal of 'inventory'

then in main

```
 #include "part.h"

struct part inventory[MAX_PARTS];
int main(void)
{
    char code;

    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter operation code: ");
        scanf(" %c", &code);
        while (getchar() != '\n')   
            ;
        switch (code) {
        case 'i': insert();
            break;
        case 's': search();
            break;
        case 'u': update();
            break;
        case 'p': print();
            break;
        case 'q': return 0;
        default:  printf("Illegal code\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
  

   }
}
```